# Chrome Not Setting Cookie

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, google-chrome-devtools

I'm trying to debug an issue with Chrome not setting cookies in my app. One thing I tried was setting a cookie manually from the console using:

```
document.cookie = "foo=bar";
```

In FF, I see the cookie in FireCookie. In Chrome, the command executes, but there is no cookie created (so far as I can tell from the "Resources" tab).

Can someone test this and confirm the same behavior? Why does this happen?

Answer (score 0):

I've already been where you are. Google Chrome appears to have some bug/feature (?) that prevents some cookies to be set in localhost.

EDIT: try adding the following command line flag or switch to your Chrome shortcut:

--enable-file-cookies

[Source](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=23fd2349855c0f17&hl=en)

Comment: Yea, that didn't work. What's weird is if you run console.log(document.cookie) - you'll see them output - just not in the Resources tab.

Comment: @JoshuaMcGinnis Which is your OS?

Comment: Chrome 13.0.782.215 m (latest) in Win7.

Answer (score 0):

This is working correctly for me (tested in Stable 13 and Dev 15 on OS X). Changes appear both in both the Resources devtools tab and in the `document.cookie` variable.

What version of Chrome are you running?

Comment: Hmm. Odd. I'm on Chrome 13.0.782.215 m in Win7. Can you try it on localhost? Also, did you have to refresh to see it in the Resources tab or did it just show up?

Comment: `localhost` or not shouldn't matter. Or do you mean `file://` URLs?

Comment: I mean localhost. It shouldn't matter, but the OP mentioned a bug in Chrome with setting cookies on localhost. If it works for you on localhost, that's useful information.